# SAS Expander Drive Compatibility

Tags: storage, sas

To my knowledge a SAS Expander reports the hard drives transparent to the Host or Raid Controller.

If I want to use 4k native drives (4kn), do the Expander also have to be capable of 4kn drives or is it enough if the Host Controller is capable of 4kn drives?

Specifically, it is about the LSI Logic SAS X28 Expander (3Gb/s) built in the [Supermicro SuperChassis 933E1-R760B](http://www.supermicro.com/products/chassis/3U/933/SC933E1-R760.cfm).

Is it possible to use a 6Gb/s or a 12Gb/s SAS Controller with this expander or are there any limitations? Normally SAS should be backwards compatible.
Speed is here not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> do the Expander also have to be capable of 4kn drives or is it enough
>   if the Host Controller is capable of 4kn drives?

Just the controller is enough.

> Is it possible to use a 6Gb/s or a 12Gb/s SAS Controller with this
>   expander or are there any limitations?

Sure, why not.